# What is the difference between the regular expressions [^\d\s] and [\D\S]

Tags: regex

Can somebody explain the difference between `[^\d\s]` and `[\D\S]`?

The description from http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html is not really clear:

> Be careful when using the negated shorthands inside square brackets.
>   `[\D\S]` is not the same as `[^\d\s]`. The latter matches any
>   character that is neither a digit nor whitespace. It matches `x`, but
>   not `8`. The former, however, matches any character that is either not
>   a digit, or is not whitespace. Because all digits are not whitespace,
>   and all whitespace characters are not digits, `[\D\S]` matches any
>   character; digit, whitespace, or otherwise.

They seem to be same for me. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Read on [Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) from Oracle's official Java Tutorials and Find complete list of [Java Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) here with full description.

Comment: Did one of the answers solve your problem? I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If an answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark on the left, as this is how the reputation system works (accepting an anwer gives reputation to both the answerer and to you). Of course there is no obligation to do so. Later when you have more reputation you can also upvote questions. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO rep tutorial. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[^\d\s]
```

will match a single character that is NOT a digit or whitespace.

```
[\D\S]
```

will match a single character that IS a non-digit or non-whitespace.

Since every character is either not a digit or not whitespace, the second regex will match any character.

It's equivalent to the difference between:

```
if (!(isdigit(c) || isspace(c))) ...
```

and

```
if (!isdigit(c) || !isspace(c)) ...
```

Note that the following would be equivalent to the first one (by deMorgan's law):

```
if (!isdigit(c) && !isspace(c)) ...
```

Answer (score 6):

ooga's answer is correct, but I see that it is still not clear for you. Sometimes it is useful to hear an explanation in different words, so let me try. It seems to me that the misunderstanding is really quite simple. Jan Goyvaerts (the author of the site you read) is not describing a particular regex feature, just a consequence of the character class logic. Let's start at the beginning

1. A character class such as `[abc]` means "match one character that is *either* `a` **OR** `b` **or** `c`. Note that it doesn't mean "match one character that is `a` **AND** `b` **AND** `c`, that would not make any sense.
2. A negated character class such as `[^abc]` means "match one character that is *neither* `a` *nor* `b` *nor* `c`, in other words it is not `a` **AND** not `b` **AND** not `c`. Notice that number 1 is all about **OR**, and that number 2 is all about **AND**.
3. Therefore `[^\d\s]` means "match one character that is not a digit **AND** not a whitespace", while
4. `[\D\S]` means "match one character that is either a non-digit **OR** a non-whitespace"

You can see that 3 and 4 are completely different.

**What does `[\D\S]` mean?**

We are allowed to "match one character that is either a non-digit **OR** a non-whitespace". A non-digit can be for instance a tab character. Okay, so we are allowed to match a tab character, and the `\D` in fact allows us to match any whitespace, because a whitespace, such as tab, is never a digit. Now let's look at the `\S`. A non-whitespace can mean for instance a `9` character, so the `\S` allows us to match any digit (and more characters). Because `[\D\S]` means "one character that is either `\D` **OR** `\S`", but doesn't mean "one character that is both `\D` **AND** `\S`", we are allowed to match any digit and any whitespace (and in fact any character).

**And vs Or**

The key is that in both number 1 and number 4, the character class says "match one character that is *either* or these character. *Either* is like saying **OR**. In number 3, we say *neither*. It is like saying not x **AND** not y

Comment: `i liked explanation with "C" syntax` Terrific, whatever works for you. :)

Comment: I have to say, i was having trouble understanding this, but cleared it out so well. If I were the OP of the question, I would make your answer as accepted. Thank you so much for clearing this up. I am sure many will benefit from your answer.